# Java getClickCount on touchscreen

Tags: java, double, touchscreen, tap

I'm trying to get some Java code working on a Windows 10 tablet.
I need to detect a double tap but this

```
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent evt) { 
   int clickCount = evt.getClickCount();
}
```

is always fired 2 times with the clickCount set to 1.
No double tap is recognized.
The double click works correctly out of Java ...any idea?
Is it possible the double tap is managed with a different mouse listener?