# Get Click Count Mouse Listener on Touch Screen

Tags: java, swing, awt, mouselistener

Im running a simple JFrame with a JList.

I encountered an issue just like this guy>
[Java getClickCount on touchscreen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37923323/java-getclickcount-on-touchscreen)

I know it has been posted already but there were no answers.

```
jList.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
         public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {   
             System.out.println("MouseClick: "+e.getClickCount());
             if (e.getClickCount() == 2) {
```

Comment: It's possible that the touch screen driver simply doesn't support the functionality.  Can you double tap other elements (outside of Java)?

Comment: yes, folders can be double tapped

Answer (score 1):

Code below is working..

```
public class MainTest extends JPanel {

 public MainTest() {

      addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() { 
          public void mousePressed(MouseEvent me) { 
            System.out.println(me.getClickCount()); 
          } 
        }); 

  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.getContentPane().add(new MainTest());

    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    frame.setSize(200, 200);
    frame.setVisible(true);
  }
```

}

Comment: On a touch screen?  What type of touch screen?

Comment: POS machine touchscreen